# Android, can not make keyboard visible with InputMethodManager

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I cannot make the keyboard dynamically visible on a editText.

```
            //should show the Keyboard
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        editText.requestFocus();

        final InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);



            //or this also does not work
        mgr.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED ,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Here is the xml-Code of the EditText:

```
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/searchHeaderView"
            android:textSize="13dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:hint="@string/searchViewHint"

            />
```

In the same App in another Activity it works with another EditText.

Comment: I hope you are making progress.  If my answer helped you, please up-vote or mark it correct.  This helps you gain reputation and also helps others find useful answers easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple things to try:

One, make sure the editText is actually getting focus.  Add an OnFocusChangeListener and then either put a breakpoint in the listener or generate some trace output.

Two, put a delay inbetween requesting focus and showing the keyboard.  Like this:

```
post (new Runnable ()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    final InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
  }
});
```